# How to cast a list to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list as a input made from tuples where the origin is the 1st object and the neighbour is the 2nd object of the tuple. 
for example :

```
inp : lst = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c',''),('a','c')]
out : {'a': ('a', ['b', 'c']), 'b': ('b', ['a']), 'c': ('c', [])}
```

first i tried to cast the list into a dictonary,
like this

```
dictonary = dict(lst)
```

but i got an error say that

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Judging by the error, you didn't provide the actual input in the question.

Comment: Specify python version: 2.x, 3.x ?

Comment: Do you really need the first element to be the same as the key?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, gets the result you want, you can blend the two operations into the same loop, make a function out of it etc, have fun! Written without Python one liners kung-fu for beginner friendliness!

```
>>> lst = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c',''),('a','c')]
>>> out = {}
>>> for pair in lst:
...     if pair[0] not in out:
...         out[pair[0]] = (pair[0], [])
...
>>> out
{'a': ('a', []), 'c': ('c', []), 'b': ('b', [])}
>>> for pair in lst:
...     out[pair[0]][1].append(pair[1])
...
>>> out
{'a': ('a', ['b', 'c']), 'c': ('c', ['']), 'b': ('b', ['a'])}
```

Comment: A `pair` in `lst` is never in `out`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: `if pair not in out:` is a tautology

Comment: Just typo, should have been `pair[0]`, to see if the first element in the pair is a key in the out dict yet

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably inside a try / except block:

```
lst = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c',''),('a','c')]

out = dict()

for k, v in lst:
    try:
        if v != '':
            out[k][1].append(v)
        else:
            out[k][1].append([])

    except KeyError:
        if v != '':
            out[k] = (k, [v])
        else:
            out[k] = (k, [])

print out
```

Which gives:

```
{'a': ('a', ['b', 'c']), 'b': ('b', ['a']), 'c': ('c', [])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just here to mention `setdefault`

```
lst = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c',''),('a','c')]

d = {}
for first, second in lst:
    tup = d.setdefault(first, (first, []))
    if second and second not in tup[1]:
        tup[1].append(second)
```