# list in the value of a dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am trying to write a function that contains a `dict` in a way that the value of every key looks in the following order:
for exmple if the function got the following list:

```
list = [(a,b),(a,c)(f,q)]
```

it would create this:

```
dict = {'a':('a',['b','c'],'f':('f',['q'])}


def create_dict(self, link_list):
    """
    creating a dict 
    :param link_list:
    :return:
    """
    collector = {}
    for tup in link_list:
        if tup[0] not in collector:
            collector[str(tup[0])] = (tup[0], [tup[1]])
        else:
            collector[tup[0]][1].append(tup[1])
```

I'm having some problems with the syntax and how to approach the list in the value of every key.

Comment: What's the logic behind your expected output?

Comment: This should work fine as I see. What kind of error do you get? Or how does the output differ from the expected output? And why do you want to store the key redundantly (both as the key of the dict and the first element of the value tuple)?

Comment: i want to make a dict if articles(style wikipedia) and the key represent the article and the the keys represnt the articles that got a link in the article itself.

Comment: i am getting this:
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: and in the end i want the key will be a string and the "key" in the value will be an object of the class i will store there, and in this way when i want to get to an article i can reach to the article itself and all the articles that linked to it (sorry for the spelling btw, withput auto corrector im a mess)

Comment: Is this homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455157/how-to-cast-a-list-to-a-dictionary/34455487?noredirect=1#comment56653307_34455487

Comment: yes..it looks like this student having similar problems. and the exmple he gave is like we got in the paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a typo on the first line.

```
list = [(a,b),(a,c)(f,q)]  # missing comma
# should be:
list = [(a,b),(a,c),(f,q)]
```

In your version, `(a, c)` is a tuple and then without a comma, the `(f, q)` after it represents calling that as a function with `f` and `q` as parameters.

Also, don't use built-in names for variables. Name it `list_` instead, at least.

---

*Edit:* wrt "represents calling that *as a function*" == or rather, *as a callable*.

Comment: yes, its took me a while, the problem was cause i dont know the syntax of the dict so good i assune the problem is in my code...thnx

Comment: Welcome to SO. Typically you should Upvote answers which were helpful and Accept the best one for you.